# Dependency resolution in NPM

Tags: npm

Consider the following:

- A project has a dependency for package X @1.2.3
- A project may need to install package Y.
- Package Y has a dependency for package X @2.3.4
- The version 2 of package X is not backwards compatible with version 1.

Can this cause issues of any kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `npm install`ed them in the default way, your project is safe from dependency conflicts.

---

Just to be sure, look for those dependencies in the `package-lock.json` file and you should immediately notice that certain package dependencies are managed differently from project dependencies. In particular, this is a simplified entry created when you install `X@1.2.3`.

```
"node_modules/X": {
  "version": "1.2.3",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then you install `Y`, that depends on `X@2.3.4`.

```
"node_modules/Y": {
  "version": "x.y.z",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "X": "2.3.4"
  },
}
```

However, since `X@2.3.4` has not been installed yet, a new entry is automatically created:

```
"node_modules/Y/node_modules/X": {
  "version": "2.3.4",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
},
```

As you can see, npm detects the potential dependency conflict: instead of registering the package in the global `node_modules` folder, npm installs it inside the `node_modules` folder of the package installed. You could have more than 2 nested level of `node_modules` if there are conflictual dependencies inside `node_modules/Y/node_modules` too.

---

I showed you an example of `package-lock.json` because understanding dependency management is straightforward looking at it, even if big. Nonetheless, in case you do not use it (I hope you do), npm reasons in the same way and you are never going to experience a dependency hell. The only exception is when you manually change semantic versioning expression allowing a major variation, but you must know what you are doing.